# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict' | PySpark

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark

I am not well versed with pyspark and that's why I am facing this very simple issue.

I've trained a `MultiPerceptronClassifier()` model by calling `fit` on it and saved the model by this: `model.write().overwrite().save(mPath)`.

Now I want to load this model and do the prediction on test datatset. This my code for that:

```
spark_context = SparkContext()
sql_context    = SQLContext(spark_context)

model = MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel()
model.load(mPath)

vector_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=input_df.columns.tolist(), outputCol='features')

# input_df is a pandas DF
input_df         = sql_context.createDataFrame(input_df)
input_vector     = vector_assembler.transform(spark_input_df)

model.predict(input_vector)
```

At the last line, I get this error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'`. I tried `model.transform()` as well, but got same error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transform'`.

Does anybody knows what is the correct way to load a save pyspark model and get the prediction on test dataset?

Comment: `model` is `None`. You can try all the methods you want, it doesn't have them.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I understand that. But I have loaded the mode so I'm not understanding how it is `None`. Maybe there is peculiar way to load models in PySpark. I am looking for that.

Comment: You are probably executing different code than you have shown here, because if `model` was None at the last line, it was also None at the line `mode.load(mPath)`, and None doesn't have a method `load` either.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry but the code is same. Even, I'm printing the `type` of the `model` before calling `predict` and I can see `TYPE:  <class 'pyspark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel'>`.

Comment: You should include the complete traceback, not just one line.

Comment: Also I dont see spark_input_df defined was input_df         = sql_context.createDataFrame(input_df) supposed to be spark_input_df?